# NAT translation giving negative port numbers

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, port

I write to you about something that happened about 15 years ago.  And while I spoke to one person who confirmed the possibility, I remain hopeful for a better explanation.
About 15 years ago, I bought a 4 port netgear router and setup a dedicated Quake 3 server on a spare computer.  (Pentium 3's were slow and everyone had more than one back then.  hehe.)  After some initial difficulty, I was able to get things running but not in the normal way.   I was getting the default port initially but I believe NAT translation altered the port to something else.  I would sometimes get a negative port number.

example xx.xxx.xx.xx:-1396

It wasn't easy finding out how to connect to my own server except through LAN and as the weeks went by I slowly learned more and I write with confidence the events that transpired.  I learned how to connect directly to the server adding parameters to the shortcut icon but only if the port number was less than 5 digits. The negative (-) in front takes up a space on the 5 total digits and if the port was 5 digits the negative sign made it six and the last number was both visible but unusable.  It would not appear on the in-game server list during those times and I think I remember teaching the fellas how to connect directly.

I have never seen anything that speaks of negative ports.

Could someone elaborate?
If the question is too broad, then more specifically, assuming that my words are true (they are), I would think the 20 of us that played back then aren't the only ones that know of this.  The questions that come next for me are was it a bug that got fixed?  or a tech that is not in use?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your question, but whatever. The port is an unsigned 16-bit integer. Whatever software you have probably interprets it as a signed integer, resulting in negative values for ports over 32768.

Comment: Amazing what 15 years can do.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Port numbers are 16-bit unsigned - I suspect that the software was incorrectly displaying them as signed values...

`-1396` is `0xFA8C`, which is `64140`.

Quake 3 uses the following ports by default [[ref]](https://portforward.com/quake-3/):

> TCP: 27950,27952,27960,27965
>
> UDP: 27950,27952,27960,27965

So this is a bit odd, unless you're quoting a random negative number, or set Quake 3 to listen on non standard ports.

`27950` would be `-37586` if displayed as a signed value.

Comment: Actually, 27950 will just be 27950. It doesn’t have the MSB set and as such is not considered negative.